# Finding an holomorphic bijective map between $\{z:|z|<1\}\backslash [a,1)$ and the upper half of the unit circle where $a > 0$

Tags: complex-analysis

> Given $D = \{z:|z|<1\}\backslash [a,1), a>0$ and $R = \{z:|z|<1, Im(z)>0\}$ find an holomorphic bijective map $f: D\to R$

I'm struggling to find a transformation that will get me closer to a more standard domain (e.g. a half plane). I thought maybe $z \mapsto Log(z)$ could give me a strip of the plane without some interval, but I'm not sure excatly how it will look like.

Note: in the course we call such maps Isomorphisms, but it didn't seem like the name is used in this context anywhere else. I think Biholomorphism is the most common name for this?

Comment: have you considered the functions $z^n$?

Comment: would $z\mapsto z^2$ would be enough to get to the unit circle? it sounds too simple.

Comment: Oh sorry, I though you were removing the non negative real axis $[0,1)$, but you only remove part of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, map $R$ to the slit unit disc $S:=\mathbb D\backslash[0,1)$ by $f_1(z)=z^2$. Next, map $S$ to $D$ by $f_2(z)=\frac{a+z}{1+az}$. Note that $f_2$ is an automorphism of $\mathbb D$ which maps reals to reals and satisfies $f_2([0,1])=[a,1]$. Now, $f_2\circ f_1$ maps $R$ to $D$, and hence $f_1^{-1}\circ f_2^{-1}$ maps $D$ to $R$.